# listField always empty

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I'd like to add a field to `defaultContext`, which will make a list of links available to all pages. Since I don't think I can change `defaultContext` itself, I've created a function which adds a `listField` to `defaultContext` and replaced all references to `defaultContext` with it. While the program complies, my new `listField` is empty.

This is my latest attempt.

```
-- site.hs
match "index.html" $ do
    route idRoute
    compile $ do
        links <- sortByTitle =<< loadAll "links/*"
        let indexCtx =
                listField "links" linkCtx (return links) `mappend`
                constField "title" "Home"                `mappend`
                myCtx

        getResourceBody
            >>= applyAsTemplate indexCtx
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" indexCtx
            >>= relativizeUrls

match "templates/*" $ compile templateBodyCompiler

myCtx =
  listField "navItems" defaultContext (loadAll "nav/*") `mappend`
  defaultContext

-- nav/item.markdown
---
title: nav item 1
---

-- templates/default.html
<ul>
    $for(navItems)$
        $title$
    $endfor$
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are loading an item, you need to specify a compilation target with that item – see [load](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.8.3.2/docs/Hakyll-Core-Compiler.html#v:load) function.

> **load** :: (Binary a, Typeable a) => Identifier -> Compiler (Item a)
>
> Load an item compiled elsewhere. If the required item is not yet compiled, the build system will take care of that automatically.

Adding a simple (no `route` is required) compiler should fix it:

```
match "nav/*" $ compile pandocCompiler
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my example Hakyll project is a bit too contrived. In practice, those "links" will actually be posts, which also exist as their own top-level `match` entry. When I introduce them to `myCtx`, I get a "Dependency cycle" compile error. Do you know how I'd address that? I'm happy to create another question, if it seems worthwhile.

Comment: That can be done using [snapshots](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/05-snapshots-feeds.html).